# Extract a section from PDF-File

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-parsing

My goal is to extract the Abstract of a PDF-File.

Is there a possibility to extract the text after a keyword (Abstract) and or search for a specific font style and extract a section of a Document?

Currently, I'm using PDFBox to extract the text but I don't know to get the content of a certain section from a PDF-File.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: You can extract parts by keyword or style but you have to do some coding for it. There are multiple questions here explaining how to determine the style of text by overriding `writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions)` and checking the `TextPosition` instances accordingly. Sometimes you also have to override `processTextPosition`.